# Use colon as filename separator in zsh tab completion

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I have many programs which take filename arguments as one(or more) of

```
path/to/file
scp:path/to/file.ext
ark:/abs/path/to/file.ext
```

Is it possible make zsh complete filenames after some keywords followed by colon?

In bash you can do this by adding `:` to the COMP_WORDBREAKS variable.

---

Thanks to Gilles, I manage to work like this.

```
$ cat ~/.zshrc
...
function aftercolon() {
  if compset -P 1 '*:'; then
    _files "$expl[@]"
  else
    _files "$expl[@]"
  fi
}

autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
compdef aftercolon hello olleh
```

Now in commands `hello` and `olleh`, completion after : works as expected.

I think there might be better way since:

1. I have odd if/else clause since the commands also take filename without prefix.
2. And since I have many commands take this kind of argument, I need to add  names of every commands. <s>I want to apply this to all commands if possible.</s> It is also okay to apply this to all commands if it is easier

--

For those who may need, now I found slightly simpler way.
Insert following in your .zshrc file

```
function aftercolon() {
  compset -P '*:'                   # strip stuff up to last :
  compset -S ':*'                   # strip stuff after next colon
  _default -r '\-\n\t /:' "$@"      # do default completion on this
}

compdef aftercolon cmd1 cmd2 cmd3 cmd4 
# to apply to all commands
compdef aftercolon -first-  # https://superuser.com/questions/1080452/add-strings-to-zsh-tab-completion-for-all-commands-and-arguments
```

Comment: That's a repeat of [your SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50488627/use-colon-as-filename-separator-in-zsh-tab-completion/50498549) which I've already answered, there's no point in repeating that question here. The follow-up questions you asked in comments are a completely different question. If you want to get answers to those question, please edit this question to formulate what you want clearly.

Comment: @Gilles The question here clearly formulates all I want. I just want to know the zsh equivalent of `COMP_WORDBREAKS` which works well with 'MANY programs'.

Comment: anyway I copied follow-up question from SO.

Comment: *Many commands* is completely different from *all commands*. Ignoring the prefix is also different from completing the prefix and the suffix separately. And having an optional prefix is also different from having a mandatory prefix. The bash feature you mention doesn't even do the same thing, although it occasionally can have the same effect (it it works for you, you're really not picky about getting good completions), so if you were asking the zsh equivalent of bash's `COMP_WORDBREAKS`, that would be again a completely different question.

Comment: Indeed I am not really picky about getting good completion, but just wanted to accomplish what I want in the simplest way. It's always hard to ask good question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @auditory I have the same question as OP, how can I make zsh use colon as filename separator in zsh tab completion for all commands, so that `fun -o:bar<TAB>` will auto-complete paths just like `fun -o=bar<TAB>` does for all commands

Comment: @timotheecour I made edit. hope it helps.

Comment: Can you give some examples of commands that use this syntax? Then I can try to reproduce it and look for a solution.

Comment: @auditory Can you please make your solution into an answer and accept it? Then this question won't stay open.

Comment: @MarlonRichert I did as you suggested. Thank you for the comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is old posting but as a summary,  in .zshrc

```
function aftercolon() {
  compset -P '*:'                   # strip stuff up to last :
  compset -S ':*'                   # strip stuff after next colon
  _default -r '\-\n\t /:' "$@"      # do default completion on this
}
compdef aftercolon -first-
```

Now I could complete filename after colon as well in zsh,

```
$ scp:/path/to/somef<TAB>  # now filename completion works after colon
```